# Tinkerpop Gremlin with Azure Cosmos DB Emulator: Invalid handshake response getStatus: 200 OK

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, tinkerpop, gremlin-server, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I'm following the tutorials in
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator?tabs=ssl-netstd21#api-for-gremlin
to use azure cosmos db emulator for gremlin.
But got always following error after executing `:remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote-localcompute.yaml`. Any idea for that?

```
15:42:19.834 [gremlin-driver-host-scheduler-1] ERROR org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Client - Could not initialize client for Host{address=127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:8081, hostUri=wss://127.0.0.1:8081/gremlin}
15:42:19.853 [main] ERROR org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Client - Initialization failed
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: Could not initialize 2 (minPoolSize) connections in pool. Successful connections=0. Closing the connection pool.
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:164)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:103)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:98)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Client$ClusteredClient.lambda$new$5(Client.java:584)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Client$ClusteredClient.lambda$initializeImplementation$0(Client.java:534)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1736)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.exception.ConnectionException: Could not open Connection{channel=f290e5d6 host=Host{address=127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:8081, hostUri=wss://127.0.0.1:8081/gremlin} isDead=false borrowed=0 pending=0 markedReplaced=false closing=false created=2023-03-07T14:42:19.732926600Z thread=gremlin-driver-conn-scheduler-1}
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:142)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ConnectionFactory.create(ConnectionFactory.java:34)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ConnectionPool.lambda$new$0(ConnectionPool.java:130)
        ... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.exception.ConnectionException: Could not complete connection setup to the server. Ensure that SSL is correctly configured at both the client and the server. Ensure that client WebSocket handshake protocol matches the server. Ensure that the server is still reachable.
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Channelizer$WebSocketChannelizer.connected(Channelizer.java:231)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:119)
        ... 9 common frames omitted
Caused by: io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocketClientHandshakeException: Invalid handshake response getStatus: 200 OK
        at io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocketClientHandshaker13.verify(WebSocketClientHandshaker13.java:312)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocketClientHandshaker.finishHandshake(WebSocketClientHandshaker.java:364)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocketClientProtocolHandshakeHandler.channelRead(WebSocketClientProtocolHandshakeHandler.java:93)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:93)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.extensions.WebSocketClientExtensionHandler.channelRead(WebSocketClientExtensionHandler.java:125)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:346)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:318)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1373)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1236)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1285)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:529)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:468)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:290)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        ... 1 common frames omitted
==>Configured 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:8081, but host not presently available. The Gremlin Console will attempt to reconnect on each query submission, however, you may wish to close this remote and investigate the problem directly.
```

Every step is correctly followed as described in the tutorials. (More than 10 times checked)

1. Install the emulator
2. Start the emulator, https://localhost:8081/_explorer/index.html is open automatically
3. Create DB and container in the opened explorer: db1, coll1
4. Install apache-tinkerpop-gremlin-console-3.6.0 create remote-localcompute.yaml in directory "conf" with content:

> ```
> hosts: [localhost]
> port: 8081
> username: /dbs/db1/colls/coll1
> password: C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==
> connectionPool: {enableSsl: true}
> serializer: { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV1d0, config: { serializeResultToString: true }}
> ```

5. Start gremlin server: bin\gremlin.bat
6. Connect Cosmos DB: :remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote-localcompute.yaml

Any ideas are appreciated.

I've tried to change the remote-localcompute.yaml with different configurations but no help.
Expectation is that I can continue to develop graph using gremlin and cosmos db emulator.

Comment: Please edit to show the steps you're referring to, configuration settings, etc. There should be no need for someone to visit the tutorial via the link you provided; everything should be self-contained here.

Comment: you may wish to revert to an earlier version of Gremlin Console to see if that solves the problem - CosmosDB calls for use of 3.4.x: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/gremlin/support